# How to read resource bundle in java backed webscript

Tags: alfresco

I want to read properties file in java-backed webscirpt. Specifically in java controller file.
I can read `message.success` in `change-password.get_ja.properties` like

```
msg.get("message.success");
```

But I don't know how to call in java-backed file.

Comment: How have you implemented your Java web script class? Can you post a code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class you're probably looking for is [I18NUtil](https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/spring-surf-parent/apidocs/org/springframework/extensions/surf/util/I18NUtil.html), part of SpringSurf which is available in all WebScripts.

The Alfresco [I18N wiki page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/I18N#Retrieving_localised_strings) has quite a bit more on it and its use. Basically though, where in your JS webscript you might have done:

```
msg.get("message.success");
```

Instead in Java you'll do:

```
I18NUtil.getMessage("message.success");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also, in java class controller, use `getResources().getString("message.success");`